# How to Fix ArcGIS Pro error Cannot get exclusive schema lock. Either being edited or in use by another application or service

Tags: arcgis-pro, attribute-joins, error-000464

I am trying to complete an Add Join between a shapefile and a .csv table in ArcGIS Pro. I downloaded the shapefile from a government website, and I created the CSV with my own data. I want to join them through a shared field named LINEARID.

This is my attempt. I click the "Add Join" tool and select the shapefile as the input table and the CSV as the join table. The "Input Join Field" and "Join Table Field" are both set to LINEARID. I check the box "Index Joined Fields".  I validate the join and Pro gives this dialogue box:

> Checking for invalid characters... Checking workspaces... Checking for
> field indexes... The join field LINEARID in the table
> tl_2019_42095_roads.tl_2019_42095_roads.shp is not indexed. To improve
> performance, we recommend that an index be created. The join field
> LINEARID in the table
> tl_2019_42095_roads.LINEARID_Easton_ticketcount_table.csv is not
> indexed. To improve performance, we recommend that an index be
> created. Checking for OIDs... Only a one-to-one join can be done
> because a unique object Id does not exist. Checking for join
> cardinality (1:1 or 1:m joins)... A one - to - one join has matched
> 8081 records. The input table has 8082 and the join table has 8082
> records.

I don't believe the lack of indexing is the problem because the validation provides me with a match of 8,081 records, which is exactly what I want.

When I run the join, it fails and ArcGIS Pro gives me the following error.

> ERROR 000464: Cannot get exclusive schema lock.  Either being edited
> or in use by another application or service.

Both the shapefile and the CSV are downloaded to my local machine; I literally imported them to ArcGIS Pro with the "Data From Path" option. Therefore, there is no one else using these files, and I have no other applications open.

I closed ArcGIS Pro and reopened it to see if

What is the problem? The answers I find online are either too confusing to follow for a newbie, use ArcCatalog which I don't have, or show screenshots of steps that aren't the same when I try them.

All I am trying to do is add columns from the CSV to the shapefile so I can map my new data. I am very new to ArcGIS Pro.

Comment: *** I closed ArcGIS Pro and reopened it to see if there was a weird loop thing, and it gave me ERROR 999999 instead.

Comment: CSV and Excel tables tend to be a bit flaky, try importing it into a DBF or geodatabase table first.

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much, Michael.